# getting an error on casting object to system.Func<object>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, caching, .net-core

I have below code where i am looping through the materials and creating osm model object and adding that to list of materials(`material vector`), and this is working fine.

Here i am adding creating duplicate osm model objects because of duplicate materials. so to avoid this i am implementing a generic concrete class that has a regular dictionary to cache the objects, and a Func factory parameter to create new items if not found in the cache

```
    public Construction AddToOsm(Model model)
    {
        if (model is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
        }

        var construction = new Construction(model);
        construction.setName($"{this.Name} - {this.AshraeClimateZone?.Name}");

        using var materials = new MaterialVector();
        foreach (var glazingMaterial in this.Layers)
        {
            if (glazingMaterial != default)
            {
                using var material = glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model); // here i am creating duplicate osm model objects 
                materials.Add(material);
            }
        }

        construction.setLayers(materials);
        return construction;
    }
```

and below is the class where i am implementing that check for creating or retrieving objects

```
public class CacheObject<T>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<object, T> _cache = new Dictionary<object, T>();
    public T GetOrCreate(object key, Func<T> createItem)
    {
        if (!_cache.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _cache[key] = createItem();
        }
        return _cache[key];
    }

}
```

and then i am using above method like as below

```
        using var materials = new MaterialVector();
        foreach (var glazingMaterial in this.Layers)
        {
            if (glazingMaterial != default)
            {
                var cacheObject = new CacheObject<FenestrationMaterial>();

                using var material = cacheObject.GetOrCreate(glazingMaterial.Id, glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model)); // getting an object casting exception
               // using var material = glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model);
                materials.Add(material);
            }
        }
```

I am getting error at this line

```
using var material = cacheObject.GetOrCreate(glazingMaterial.Id, glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model));
```

and the error is

**cannot convert from 'OpenStudio.FenestrationMaterial' to 'system.Func'**

Could any one please suggest any ideas on this how to overcome this error or any other suggestion if i am doing wrong  would be very grateful to me.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean to pass `glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model)` as a `Func<T> createItem` to `cacheObject.GetOrCreate()` method? What's happening is you're passing in the *result* of that call instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```cs
var material = cacheObject.GetOrCreate(glazingMaterial.Id, () => glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model));
```

`GetOrCreate` expects function as a second argument, but you giving it result of a function instead

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in a *result of the function call* instead of a *delegate* to `cacheObject.GetOrCreate()` - `glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model)` is not a `Func<T> createItem`. Change the all as follows:

```
using var material = cacheObject.GetOrCreate(glazingMaterial.Id, 
                                             () => glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model));
```

This change creates an *anonymous method* via a *lambda expression*, also known as a *factory method* - this will satisfy the `Func<T> createItem` parameter, *provided that `glazingMaterial.AddToOsm(model)` returns a valid `T`*

Comment: there is an issue here, every time I am going inside the if loop condition where i am checking for "!_cache.ContainsKey(key)" key and could you please suggest any idea why i am creating new everytime.

Comment: Because your key is a `class`, which is a *reference type* - you're just comparing references to boxed values instead of `Id`s - if your `id` is an `int` you should just use that as a key, or take in a second generic parameter. Generally, you should never use `object` as key